# How do I return an alternate concatenation when joining fields that may be null?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a view that uses `last_name || ', ' || first_name person_name` to concatenate two name fields into a single name field. The problem is our database has many rows where one or both fields are null. When this occurs, we end up with a single comma (both names null) or an out of place comma if one of the name fields is null.

How can I address this situation? Ideally the following will happen:
If both fields are null, leave the resulting field null. Don't display a comma.
If one field is null, don't display the comma. Display the non-null field.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT last_name
  ||
  CASE
    WHEN last_name IS NULL
    OR first_name  IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    ELSE ', '
  END
  || first_name
FROM <your table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT last_name
      ||
      CASE CONCAT(first_name , person_name) as fullname
      WHEN NULL
      THEN NULL
      ELSE 
      CONCAT(',',fullname)
      END
    from ...
```

- First concat both first_name and person_name and check whether it
  returns null or not null
- if null just return null but if it is not concat a comma the
  beginning and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a NVL2() http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl2.php

```sql
select nvl2(last_name, first_name||', '||last_name, first_name) as person_name
from   ...;
```

This example would return ,last_name if first_name is null.